# While me duplica los campos

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo un while en PHP y me duplica los campos, me gustaria que solo apareciese el select con los nombres dentro

PHP

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id_operari=$row['tre_operario'];
    $nom_treballador = $row['tre_nom']." ".$row['tre_cognom'];
    echo "<div class='caja'>";
    echo "<select name='operari_sel' id='operari_sel'>
    <option value='default'>Selecciona un trabajador</option>
    <option value='$id_operari'>".$row["tre_operario"]." - ".$row["tre_nom"]." ".$row["tre_cognom"]."</option>
    </select>";
  }
```

[image: duplicado]

Como podeis comprobar me sale duplicado, me gustaria que solo saliese 1, con todos los nombres dentro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es poner las etiquetas de apertura y cierre del `select` y la opción por defecto fuera del `while` (son partes que no se tienen que repetir por cada registro):

```
        echo "<div class='caja'>
              <select name='operari_sel' id='operari_sel'>
              <option value='default'>Selecciona un trabajador</option>";

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id_operari=$row['tre_operario'];
            $nom_treballador = $row['tre_nom']." ".$row['tre_cognom'];
            echo "<option value='$id_operari'>".$row["tre_operario"]." - ".$row["tre_nom"]." ".$row["tre_cognom"]."</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>
              </div>";
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió!

Comment: @Luis, me alegro 